# Select multiple item from a table not working

Tags: php, sql

I have the below php code to select a file in a directory from my database.
First I tried to get all sub folders inside the main directory and now I want to select file from the database that exists in those directories. But I am having problem doing this.

My directory structure looks like this:
`maindir/>Sub1/>Sub2/>Sub3/Sub4/>etc...`

```
  <?php
    $currentBas = basename(dirname(__FILE__));
    $dirs = array_filter(glob('*'), 'is_dir');
            foreach ($dirs as $i => $fileinfo){
            $result = end(explode('/', $fileinfo)); 
            $listdirs  = ",".basename($result);  
//echo $listdirs; here it print  ,Sub1,Sub2,Sub3,Sub4 but outside of it only return Sub1
    }
    //echo $listdirs; here i suppose to get something like this 
    ,Sub1,Sub2,Sub3,Sub4  but it only return Sub1 

    $toutput;
    $db = new DBController();       
    $db->prepare('SELECT dirchildurls FROM jailorgchild WHERE jailchildbasname = :base');
    $db->bind(':base', $currentBas.$listdirs);
    $db->execute();
    $toutput = $db->getAll(); 
    $db->free();
    ?>
```

Comment: `$listdirs` overwritten everytime of `foreach` loop. Use `$listdirs .=`

Comment: @u_mulder it show this Notice: Undefined variable: listdirs in

Comment: Init `$listdirs` with empty value before the loop

Comment: @u_mulder okay but it didn't select anything from database

Comment: @u_mulder what about my select SELECT dirchildurls FROM jailorgchild WHERE jailchildbasname = main,Sub1,Sub2,Sub3

Comment: I don't know what about your select. Maybe it's wrong?

Comment: Please someone answer my question

Comment: Are you sure that `jailchildbasname` field in your table has __value__ `'main,Sub1,Sub2,Sub3'`?

Comment: @u_mulder some might be empty while some has some value to return